# cross-compile freetype for DOS with OpenWatcom under Linux

Tags: cross-compiling, dos, freetype2, watcom

More out of fun than anything I'm writing a program for an old MS-DOS machine. I'm using Linux (Fedora 19) as my development machine and OpenWatcom 1.9 to compile my code.

Now, I'd like to use FreeType (2.5.2) for my project but I'm having trouble getting it to use OpenWatcom. Running `make setup watcom` like the documentation suggests doesn't work, it still automatically detects a unix system:

```
$ make setup watcom

FreeType build system -- automatic system detection

The following settings are used:

  platform                    unix
  compiler                    cc
  configuration directory     ./builds/unix
  configuration rules         ./builds/unix/unix.mk

If this does not correspond to your system or settings please remove the file
`config.mk' from this directory then read the INSTALL file for help.

Otherwise, simply type `make' again to build the library,
or `make refdoc' to build the API reference (the latter needs python).

cd builds/unix; /bin/sh ./configure 
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out

...

checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating unix-cc.mk
config.status: creating unix-def.mk
config.status: creating ftconfig.h
config.status: executing libtool commands
make: *** No rule to make target `watcom'.  Stop.
```

Using `./configure --host=i286-pc-msdos` doesn't change a thing as well. The problem seems to be that the FreeFype build system only does cross-compilation with GCC. Do I really have to setup a whole build-environment inside DosBox or can FreeType be convinced to use OpenWatcom instead of GCC?

Unfortunately, there isn't much to be found on the internet. It almost looks like nobody uses DOS anymore...

Comment: Is there a way of setting the target rather than the host? It would seem to me that the host is the machine you're compiling on and the target the machine you want to run the compiled binary on.